# Having trouble with win32com in python

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

when i run the command

```
import win32com.client
exl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

im getting the following error.. how can i solve this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024893, 'The system cannot find the path specified.', None, None)
```

Comment: instead of     `code` exl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
if i run this     `code` speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
there is no error, i think it is the problem with excel... im using office 2019

Answer (score 0):

check what your excel programID or shortcut is from your excel properties, it might be different. This only gives you access to read environment variables where your application ID is stored.

Comment: my excel program id is 14792 i got it from the task manager. So what should i do now.. im new to win32com

Comment: You can use that ID, or the readable name ID - programme name in dispatch.